# Debugging a fortran dll called by a C++ program in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fortran

I'm having problems debugging a C++ program which uses a Fortran DLL. I'd like to step through the C++ code until I hit the call to the Fortran DLL and then step into the fortran code. Is this possible and if so, how would I do this?

Thanks,
James

Comment: If you try stepping into the fortran code, doesn't Visual Studio prompt you with a message asking to either view the assembly, or to provide a source file?

Comment: If you have the Fortran code, place some milestone logs inside that dll, build again and track the flow inside the logs.

Comment: Hi, No I get no dialog, it just jumps to the next line in the fortran.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more about the milestone logs? Is that just writing it out to a text file?

Comment: Do you have the .pdb file for both the C++ executable and Fortran DLL.  You will need both to be able to step through the code in both languages.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible.

The Fortran DLL needs to have been compiled and linked with the appropriate debug settings.  Exactly how to do that depends on the Fortran compiler that you are using.

The VS debugger also needs to be able to find the pdb for the DLL.  Typically this is only an issue if the DLL was built by a different solution, or on a different computer.

Messages in the Output pane and entries in the Modules pane can be used to confirm/diagnose issues with availability of debug information.